# How to do a kernel with horizontal stripes fast

Tags: python, numpy

I wanna do a kernel of zeros and ones. I have a list with pairs of heights (e.g. [[191.0, 243.0], [578.0, 632.0]]. What I want to do is set ones in the kernel on those rows with height between the values of a pair of heights.

Example image about what I want to do (in this case 2 pairs, the values above):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCavq.png)

My method makes a double loop but takes minutes to execute. Is there any faster way to do this? Here is the code:

```
mascara = numpy.zeros((height, width),numpy.uint8)
#print(mascara)

for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):  #For each element of the kernel (kernel=mascara)
        indice_parejas = 0
        while indice_parejas < numero_de_parejas:       #indice_parejas: index that indicates the pair we are checking
            #print(i,j)                                 #numero_de_parejas: how many pairs we have          
            if i > vector_mascara[indice_parejas][0] and i < vector_mascara[indice_parejas][1]:     #If it is between a pair
                mascara[i][j] = 1
                break               #we don't have to check the others pairs because we know it is in this pair (get out of the loop)
            else:
                indice_parejas = indice_parejas + 1
```

Comment: please learn about numpy: slicing and assignment to slices. that will solve your problem.

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, it is quite simple:

```py
for h0, h1 in hpairs:
    mask[h0:h1, :] = 1
```

##### Reproducible example

```py
w, h = 8, 4
mask = np.zeros((w, h), dtype=np.uint8)

hpairs = [
    [1,3],
    [5,6],
]

for h0, h1 in hpairs:
    mask[h0:h1, :] = 1

>>> mask
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```